# Conditional statement on jsp isn't working

Tags: java, jsp

I have this code in the `<head>` of the `.jsp` file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageId = "<c:out value="${pageData.contentId}" />";
</script>
```

And then I have this:

```
<p>
    <strong>
        Some text here

        <br>

        <c:if test="${pageId == 'how-credit-affects-interest-rate' || pageId == 'taking-control-credit-score'}">
            Display text here if conditional is true.
        </c:if>

    </strong>
</p>
```

I already tried by doing this:

```
<c:if test="${pageId eq 'how-credit-affects-interest-rate' || pageId eq 'taking-control-credit-score'}">
    Display text here if conditional is true.
</c:if>
```

And also tried with `or` instead of `||`, if I put `pageId` in the browser console, I get the proper result but still I don't get it working.

Why this could be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the stuff in the script tag executes on the browser after the jsp execution has finished.  You can't use `pageId` server side, it doesn't exist in that context.

Try

```
<c:if test="${pageData.contentId eq 'how-credit-affects-interest-rate' || pageData.contentId eq 'taking-control-credit-score'}">
```

Comment: So, which could be the solution here?

Comment: Added an example to try